# Is it safe to move and delete file in File::Find::find?

Tags: perl

```
File::Find::find ( sub {
    #
    unlink if int -M $File::Find::name > 100;
    File::Copy::move $File::Find::name, "/$File::Find::dir/backup" if $File::Find::name =~ /ERROR/;
    }, $dir ）；
```

Is it safe to move and delete file in File::Find::find ?

Answer (score 4):

Delete: Yes. File::Find reads the whole directory before calling `wanted` for any file in the directory.

Move: No, since you are moving the files into a directory you might visit. But if you added the following needed snippet, it would be safe.

```
if ($_ eq 'backup') {
   $File::Find::prune = 1;
   return;
}
```

Also, you really should have the following afterwards:

```
return if !-f $_;
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine moving and deleting files.  If you are moving and deleting the directories as you are working on them it might get somewhat confusing.  The list of files and directories will be made at the start of the sub so new files and directories that you make during the sub running will not be considered

Hope this helps